# Pressing Enter while editing comment on mobile doesn't submit it

Tags: bug, comment-edits

In Chrome on Android you can post a comment by typing one, then pressing Enter on the on-screen keyboard.

If you're editing a comment, pressing Enter doesn't submit the edit, but inserts a newline instead. I've at least observed this behavior when the caret isn't at the end of the comment text, for example when inserting a word.

I use the "full site", not a mobile version.

Comment: This is a comment that I'll finish with an Enter press. Edit. Edit: edit. Main seems to behave different than Meta.